# Postmaster Notification Not sending

Tags: postmaster

I have a notification that I want to send out every day, I am using mail chimp and I have the list selected that I want to send to but no matter what values I put in the post date field or any of the three date fields, it still won't send.

Any help or advice would be great as to what values to put in what specific field in order to send the email out every day

Comment: Can you provide some further information please? Such as how you have set up the Postmaster and this particular email, whether you receive any error messages or responses etc.

Comment: When you try to send an email to yourself via `Tools > Communicate`, does it send an email then? Do you recieve it?? Are there any PHP style errors after you submit your 'communication'??? If the Communicate Tool doesn't send an email, the problem is in your email setup, not postmaster. also, have you checked the date & Time on the server??